# Как в C# из переменной int i выбрать первые 2 символа?

Tags: c#

Есть переменная:

```
 int i = 2460007644126;
```

Как выбрать только первые 2 символа переменной i, чтобы можно было выполнить проверку условием:

```
if (i == 24) { ... }
```

Comment: Если разрядность i неизвестна, то преобразовать i в строку, оставить в ней первые 2 символа и обратно преобразовать в число. Если разрядность фиксирована и известна, то поделить i на (l-2) нацело, где l разрядность Вашего числа.

Comment: Т.е., i.Convert.ToString().Substring(2,0) ?

Comment: int i это штрихкод, нужно получить первые 2 символа для определения данного штрихкода в определенную таблицу mysql (допустим db.table_barcodes_24). В таблице шк хранится в int(20)

Comment: В int (32 бита) такое значение не влезет: `2460007644126`.

Comment: Сааамый простой вариант - `int result = int.Parse($"{i}".Substring(0,2));`. Не самый лучший, но чисто выдать определенное число первых символом, вполне. Можно также так: `int result = int.Parse(string.Join("", $"{i}".Take(2)));`, тут работа с массивом, можете без труда таким способом вывести отдельно каждое число.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long i = 2460007644126;
string a = i.ToString().Substring(0, 2); // получили первые два символа
i = Convert.ToInt32(a); // преобразовали обратно в число
if (i == 24) { Console.WriteLine(i); }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Попробовал ваш вариант и он сработал. Возможно и другие предложенные варианты тоже рабочие, но проверять нету времени)

Answer (score 3):

Ну или как вариант.

```
long i = 2460007644126;
i /= (long)Math.Pow(10, Math.Max(0, (long)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10(i)) - 2));
if (i == 100) i = 10;
if (i == 24)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
long number = 2460007644126;
long lastTwoDigits = number;
while (lastTwoDigits >= 100) lastTwoDigits /= 10;
```

Один из самых оптимальных и простых способ решения

Comment: Имеет смысл рассмотреть вариант отрицательного `number`

Comment: while (Math.Abs(lastTwoDigits) >= 100) lastTwoDigits /= 10;

Comment: ну или `long lastTwoDigits = Math.Abs(number);`

Answer (score 2):

Немножечко LINQ

```
long i = 2460007644126;

IEnumerable<long> ReverseDigits(long n)
{
    while (n > 0)
    {
        yield return n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
}

i = ReverseDigits(i).Reverse().Take(2).Aggregate(0L, (a, z) => a * 10 + z);

if (i == 24)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: я бы переименовал fun в ReverseDigits

Comment: @VladD согласен

Answer (score 1):

```
long i = 2460007644126;
string a = "" + i.ToString()[0] + i.ToString()[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        long number = 2460007644126;
        long[] lastDigits = new long[2];

        int c = 0;
        while (number != 0)
        {
            lastDigits[c++ % 2] = number % 10; number /= 10;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("{0} -- {1}", lastDigits[0], lastDigits[1]);
```

В `lastDigits[0]` будет 2, в `lastDigits[1]` будет 4 если число знаков нечётное
, и наоборот если чётное

Будет работать в принципе для любого целого числа, как мне кажется простая школьная информатика, разве нет? :)

Так можно получить и любое количество знаков, все 2-ки, заменить на нужное число.

В конце, можно добавить поразрядное сложение, а-ля.
`long i = 10 * lastDigits[0] + lastDigits[1];`

Comment: Нет возможности проверить, но будет ли это работать корректно для `246000764412`?

Comment: @tym32167 по крайне мере у меня в визуалке всё работало верно :)

Comment: Я про то, куда вы пишете первую и вторую цифры. Походу если взять число на одну цифру короче, чем у вас, то результат будет неверный

Comment: @tym32167 ну, это да, я в своём ответе это учёл.
Действительно, можно бы и записывать только в первую ячейку, и когда число будет меньше или равно 10, во вторую

Comment: добрался до компа. Проверил ваш код. Для числа `246000764412` он выводит `4 -- 2`